# Can't communicate my 2 Xbee modules using API mode

Tags: arduino-mega, xbee

I want to create a network with 10 routers/end devices and one coordinator with my Xbee Pro S2C devices. For That I know I have to do it in API mode. I configured one as a coordinator (DH=0, DL=FFFF, CE=1, AP=1) and one as a router (DH=0, DL=0, CE=0, AP=1) and then I tried making them communicate with the xbee-library for Arduino.

I used this for the coordinator:

```
XBee xbee = XBee();
uint8_t *payload= "Hello!";

//XBeeAddress64 CoordinatorAddr64 = XBeeAddress64(0x0013A200, uint8_t *payload= "Hello!";0x40C8CA96); //Put the address of the node explicitly.
//XBeeAddress64 CoordinatorAddr64 = XBeeAddress64(0x0013A200, 0x4125f767); //The address DH:DL = 0 for coordinator always
XBeeAddress64 CoordinatorAddr64 = XBeeAddress64(0, 0); //The address DH:DL = 0 for coordinator always
XBeeResponse response = XBeeResponse();
ZBRxResponse rx = ZBRxResponse();
ZBTxRequest zbTx = ZBTxRequest(CoordinatorAddr64, payload, 7);
ZBTxStatusResponse txStatus = ZBTxStatusResponse();
ModemStatusResponse msr = ModemStatusResponse();

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  xbee.setSerial(Serial1);

  Serial.println(("ZB Node-" + String(NODE_TYPE)+ " FW Version:"+ String(NODE_VERSION)));
  Serial.println(("Arduino Setup Finished on " + String(NODE_NAME) + ". Console should show up!"));
  Serial.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
} 

void loop() 
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly
  String sample;          //Our incoming messages from coordinator will be collected in this variable.
  uint16_t senderShortAddress;

  xbee.send(zbTx);

  delay(5000);
}
```

And for my router, I'm simply trying to receive the data and I'll send data to the coordinator when I am able to read data.

```
XBee xbee = XBee();

uint8_t *payload= "Hi!";


//XBeeAddress64 CoordinatorAddr64 = XBeeAddress64(0x0013A200, 0x40C8CA96); //Put the address of the node explicitly.
XBeeAddress64 CoordinatorAddr64 = XBeeAddress64(0x0013A200, 0x4125f755); //The address DH:DL = 0 for coordinator always
XBeeResponse response = XBeeResponse();
ZBRxResponse rx = ZBRxResponse();
ZBTxRequest zbTx = ZBTxRequest(CoordinatorAddr64, payload, 4);
ZBTxStatusResponse txStatus = ZBTxStatusResponse();
ModemStatusResponse msr = ModemStatusResponse();


void setup() 
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(STATUS_LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ALIVE_LED, OUTPUT);

   //initialize timer-1 (16 bit timer) for normal timer overflow mode
  Timer1.initialize(500000); //defined in value/1000000 toggleStateFn called every 500 milliseconds.
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(toggleStateFn);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  xbee.setSerial(Serial);

  Serial.println(("ZB Node-" + String(NODE_TYPE)+ " FW Version:"+ String(NODE_VERSION)));
  delay(3000);
  Serial.println(("Arduino Setup Finished on " + String(NODE_NAME) + ". Console should show up!"));
  Serial.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
} 

void loop() 
{
  uint16_t senderShortAddress;
  xbee.readPacket();

  if(xbee.getResponse().isAvailable()){
    Serial.print("Available ");
    Serial.println(xbee.getResponse().isAvailable());
    Serial.print("Api ID: ");
    Serial.println(xbee.getResponse().getApiId());

    XBeeAddress64 senderLongAddress = rx.getRemoteAddress64();
    senderLongAddress = rx.getRemoteAddress64();
    Serial.print(senderLongAddress.getMsb(),HEX);
    Serial.println(senderLongAddress.getLsb(),HEX);

    //Get the 16bit address of source node from incoming packet.
    Serial.print("Source Node short address:0x");
    senderShortAddress = rx.getRemoteAddress16();
    Serial.println(senderShortAddress,HEX);
  }
}
```

When I run the code I get nothing on the router.

- I checked my connections (OK, Tx1 for MEGA connected to DIN, pin3, and Rx1 connected to DOUT, pin 2);
- I verified that the signal is getting to the Xbee
- Verified the packet. Connected it to serial 1 and just printed it to the serial console and I see that the packet goes correctly to the Xbee (7E 00 15 10 01 00 7D 33 A2 00 41 25 F7 67 FF FE 00 00 48 65 6C 6C 6F 21 00 63) and I can see that the same packet is going in the signal
- When I first got the modules I just started printing from one side to the other and it worked. It was in transparent mode and not in API mode.

The thing is that I can't even get one coordinator and one router to communicate and I want to create a coordinator-10router network. Which means I'm in trouble. Could there be something wrong in my configuration? Is there something wrong in my code? Perhaps I'm using the wrong XbeeAddress64? Is it a problem with the library I'm using?

Comment: I'm struggling with XBEE communication myself, but should xbee.setSerial(Serial) be xbee.setSerial(**Serial1**)?

Comment: The library didn't work so i built my own much simpler library. It started working just by coincidence. The problem was in my physical connections to the xbee module. The signals were either not getting to the module or to the arduino (I wasn't using a shield, I simply solderedwires to the pins and then to a protoboard and I found out that the protoboard was faulty)